# ReactJS keep asking for key: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `PostCard`

Tags: reactjs, react-key-index

i don't know why react keep asking for the key even when the key is added.

i have a component that render some posts but each posts is rendered in it's own component and it's inside a component that come from **Swiper**

my component look like this:

```
export default function Posts() {

const postsCards = posts.map(post => {
   return <SwiperSlide className="w-25" key={post._id}>
              <PostCard post={post} key={post._id}/>
          </SwiperSlide>
})

return (
<div className="container">
    <h4>Top posts</h4>
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView= 'auto'
      spaceBetween= {10}
      observer= {true}
      observeParents={true}
    >
        {postsCards}
    </Swiper>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: It says keys should be unique. Check if they are not the same using post._id. Also you might want to show PostCards code too.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you have the same key for a SwiperSlide and for a PostCard too. You should have a unique key for each of them.

Comment: i think this is not the problem, because even i remove it, it's keep throwing an error, i have added the key to "PostCard" to check if it can solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Adding the key attribute to just the Parent component SwiperSlide would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@user9779830](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9779830/user9779830)

The SwiperSlide and PostCard have same key. I have created a solution where the key of PostCard component is set to the hash of post._id:

```
hashCode = s => s.split('').reduce((a,b)=>{a=((a<<5)-a)+b.charCodeAt(0);return a&a},0)

export default function Posts() {

const postsCards = posts.map(post => {
   return <SwiperSlide className="w-25" key={post._id}>
              <PostCard post={post} key={hashCode(post._id.toString())}/>
          </SwiperSlide>
})

return (
<div className="container">
    <h4>Top posts</h4>
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView= 'auto'
      spaceBetween= {10}
      observer= {true}
      observeParents={true}
    >
        {postsCards}
    </Swiper>
</div>
)
}
```

As you can see, the key for both of the components will be different as the PostCard component uses the hash of 'post._id'

Comment: you will only need key for the SwiperSlide component, not the PostCard.

Comment: Let's see what worked for the user, if the problem is solved by only setting key to SwiperSlide component, I will edit my answer.

Comment: i have try this method, but it's not solve the problem. help me please

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a solution, but using the index as a key for now, allows you to identify whether your post._id is unique.

```
const postsCards = posts.map((post, index) => {
   return <SwiperSlide className="w-25" key={`${post._id}-${index}`}>
              <PostCard post={post}/>
          </SwiperSlide>
})
```

If it's no longer returning error with the above codes, then it's likely you have duplicated `posts` in your posts array.